# Error Building Codename One Project on Intellij with codename one 6.0 (Reflective error)

Tags: java, codenameone

Am trying to send a codename one project to the build server that was made using codename one 6.01. it works on the emulator though at a point i get an `IllegalAccessException` during runtime after using scheduleBackground task so i removed it. this is the error message i get when trying to build:

> /home/coldcode01/IdeaProjects/Tawada/build.xml:66: Compile failed; see
>   the compiler error output for details.

[image: snapshot of error]

Comment: Check out the tip on disabling the intellij tree mode here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intellij-idea-ram.html this will show you the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Java 11 but the build hint is set to Java 8. The problem was most likely with

```
<collections>.foreach(()->{•••});
```

because lambdas I used in event listeners are fine but the ones i used with the foreach method to iterate through collection elements failed.

What I did was to convert all ... foreach..  to use itetrator i.e.

```
Iterator iter = <some collections>.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object element = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

And that solved my issue.